# ALL_{NFA} is PSPACE-complete

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, space-complexity, nondeterminism

Show that $ALL_{NFA}$ = {$\langle M\rangle : M$ is $NFA$ and $L(M) = \Sigma^*$} is $\text{PSPACE-complete}$.
I've manged to prove that the langauge is in $\text{PSPACE}$.
Indeed, it is easy to see that $\overline{ALL_{NFA}}\in \text{NPSPACE}$ (the machine just nondeterministically guess a word rejected by the automaton and this process is bounded by an appropriate space). Then, using the fact that $\text{NPSPACE} = \text{PSPACE}$, we get that $\overline{ALL_{NFA}}\in PSPACE$. Finally, as $\text{PSPACE}$ is closed under complement, we get that $ALL_{NFA} \in PSPACE$. But I did not manage to show that $ALL_{NFA}$ is $\text{PSPACE-hard}$.

Comment: 1. What is your question?  We require you to identify a specific question.  2. Please review your post carefully and [edit] it.  I see typos.  Also the sentence "...which leads to..." doesn't make sense in context; something seems wrong there.  Do you mean $\in PSPACE$?

Answer (score 2):

Let's show a generic PTIME reduction from any language in $\text{PSPACE}$ to $ALL_{NFA}$.
Let $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ be a language in PSPACE, and let $T$ be a TM that decides $L$ with polynomial space-complexity $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.  We need to show that $L\leq_p ALL_{NFA}$. So we need to define a polynomial-time reduction that on input $x$, outputs an NFA $A_x$ such that $T$ accepts $x$ iff $A_x$ accepts all its inputs.
We actually show that we can construct $A_x$ in time polynomial in $|T|$ and $s(|x|)$. Let $n = s(|x|)$, and so each configuration in the computation of $T$ on $x$ uses at most $n$ tape cells.

We define $A_x$ so that it accepts an input $y$ iff one of the following holds:

(C1) $y$ does not describe an encoding of a legal computation of $T$ on $x$, or

(C2) $y$ starts with an encoding of the initial configuration of $T$ on $x$, and contains an encoding of the accepting state of $T$.

It is not hard to see that $T$ accepts $x$ iff $A_x$ accepts all its inputs.
Indeed, if $T$ accepts $x$, then for all inputs $y$ of $A_x$, either $y$ does not describe an encoding of a legal computation of $T$ on $x$, and thus accepted by $A_x$ (due to (C1)), or $y$ describes an encoding of a legal computation of $T$ on $x$, and since $T$ accepts $x$, then $y$ encodes an accepting computation of $T$ on $x$, and thus is accepted by $A_x$ (due to (C2)).
Conversely, if $T$ rejects $x$, then the word $y$ that encodes the rejecting computation of $T$ on $x$ is rejected by $A_x$ as it does not satisfy (C1) nor (C2).

We now describe the construction of $A_x$. This is a tedious technical part, and I am taking the encoding part of it from [here](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eornak/publications/hbmc15.pdf) with minor changes:

We can write $T=\langle{\Gamma,Q,\Delta,q_0,q_{acc},q_{rej}\rangle}$, where $\Gamma$ is the tape-alphabet, $Q$ is the set of states, $\Delta \subseteq Q \times \Gamma \times Q \times \Gamma \times \{L,R\}$ is the transition relation (we use $(q,a,q',b,D)\in \Delta$ to indicate that when $T$ is in state $q$ and it reads the input $a$ in the current tape cell, it moves to state $q'$, writes $b$ in the current tape cell, and its reading head moves one cell to the left/right, according to $D$), $q_0$ is the initial state, $q_{acc}$ is the accepting state, and $q_{rej}$ is the rejecting one.

We encode a configuration of $T$ that uses at most $n = s(|x|)$ tape cells by a word of the form  $\# \gamma_1 \gamma_2 \ldots (q,\gamma_i) \ldots \gamma_{n}$. That is, the encoding of a configuration starts with a special letter $\#$, and all its other letters are in $\Gamma$, except for one letter in $Q \times \Gamma$. The meaning of such a configuration is that the $j$'th cell in $T$, for $1 \leq j \leq n$, is $\gamma_j$-labeled, the head of $T$ points at $i$'th cell, and $T$ is in the state $q$. For example, the initial configuration of $T$ on the input word $x$ is encoded as $\# (q_0,x_1) x_2 \cdots x_{|x|} b b \cdots b$ (with $n-|x|$ occurrences of $b$'s) where $b$ stands for an empty cell. We can now encode a computation of $T$ as a sequence of configurations.

Let $\Sigma'=\{\#\} \cup \Gamma \cup (Q \times \Gamma)$, and let $\# \sigma_1 \ldots \sigma_{n} \# \sigma'_1 \ldots \sigma'_{n}$ be two successive configurations of $T$. We also set $\sigma_0$, $\sigma'_0$, and $\sigma_{n+1}$ to $\#$. For each triple $\langle{\sigma_{i-1},\sigma_i,\sigma_{i+1}\rangle}$ with $1 \leq i \leq n$, we know, by the transition relation of $T$, what $\sigma'_i$ should be. In addition, the letter $\#$ should repeat exactly every $n+1$ letters. Let $next(\sigma_{i-1},\sigma_i,\sigma_{i+1})$ denote our expectation for $\sigma'_i$. For example,

- $next(\sigma_{i-1},\sigma_i,\sigma_{i+1})=\sigma_i$ if $\sigma_i=\#$, or if non of $\sigma_{i-1},\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_{i+1}$ are in $Q\times\Gamma$.
- $next((q,\gamma_{i-1}),\gamma_i,\gamma_{i+1})=
      next((q,\gamma_{i-1}),\gamma_i,\#)=$
  $ \left[ \begin{array}{ll}
      \gamma_i & \mbox{If $(q,\gamma_{i-1}, 
          q',\gamma'_{i-1},L) \in \Delta$}\\
      (q',\gamma_i) & \mbox{If $(q,\gamma_{i-1},
          q',\gamma'_{i-1},R)\in \Delta$}
      \end{array}\right]$
- $next(\gamma_{i-1},\gamma_i,(q,\gamma_{i+1}))=
  next(\#,\gamma_i,(q,\gamma_{i+1}))=$
  $ \left[ \begin{array}{ll}
      \gamma_i & \mbox{If $(q,\gamma_{i+1},
          q',\gamma'_{i+1},R)\in \Delta$}\\
      (q',\gamma_i) & \mbox{If $(q,\gamma_{i+1},
          q',\gamma'_{i+1},L)\in \Delta$}
      \end{array}\right]$
- etc...

I won't detail all the cases, but you got the idea. Also note that we have a few edge cases that we need to consider, for example, since the machine does not use more than $n$ tape cells then the case where $i = n$ and we move to the right is impossible. etc.

Now back to the answer. The idea is that every word $y$ that encodes a computation that does not contain violations of the transition function of $T$, when it uses at most $n$ tape cells, must be consistent with $next$. So the NFA $A_x$, when it reads an input $y$, guesses from its initial state to check whether $y$ satisfies $(C1)$ or $(C2)$.

When $A_x$ guesses to check condition (C1), it checks whether $y$ does not describe an encoding of a legal computation of $T$ on $x$.
We check whether $y$ is a word that satisfies at least one of the following:

- $y$ does not start with the initial configuration of $T$ on $x$, or
- $y$ is of length at least $n + 2$ and describes a violation of $next$, where $A_x$ guesses a position in $y$ and checks whether the guessed position starts with three letters $\sigma_{i-1},\sigma_{i}, \sigma_{i+1}$ describing three successive letters in the encoding and ends with a letter $\sigma'_2$, which comes $n+1$ letters after $\sigma_i$ in the encoding, yet is different than $next(\sigma_{i-1},\sigma_{i}, \sigma_{i+1})$.

When $A_x$ guesses to check condition (2), it checks whether $y$ starts with the initial configuration of $T$ on $x$, and checks whether $y$ contains a letter of the form $(q_{acc}, \gamma)$.

It is not hard to see that $A_x$ can be constructed using at most a number of states that is polynomial in $|T|$ and $n = s(|x|)$. Indeed, the length of the description of the initial configuration of $T$ on $x$ is linear in $n$. Also, the number of triples $(\sigma_{i_1}, \sigma_i, \sigma_{i+1})$ is polynomial in $|\Sigma'|$.

**Note:** the crux of the proof here is that we can check whether a computation violates the transition function of $T$ by performing a local check -- this is what $next$ does: it is sufficient to guess a window of length 3 around some position in $T$'s tape, and check whether this portion of the tape is problematic.